# Give offset result modulo 200 in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table `tbl` which consisted of 800 rows. And I need to write a query which is going to 200 rows as follows:

1

```
SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY id OFFSET 100 LIMIT 200;
```

returns

```
 id
----
101
 .
 .
 .
300
```

and it's ok, but

```
SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY id OFFSET 700 LIMIT 200;
```

returns

```
 id
----
701
 .
 .
 .
800
```

But I need to return

```
 id
----
701
 .
 .
 .
800
 1
 2
 .
 .
 .
100
```

How to modify the query in order to start returning from the begining of the table when we reach the end of it? Is it possible to do without using of `UNION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it without using a union all, but I would probably use the following:

```
with looped_table as (
  ( select id from tbl order by id )
union all
  ( select id from tbl order by id )
)
select id from looped_table offset 700 limit 200;
```